# Additional Domino - first server not responding

Tags: lotus-domino

I want to install an additional Domino as I did several times before. This one now resides on an external V-host. The "first" server I specified is in my internal network but can be reached from outside via :1352. But the remote setup tool says that it is unreachable.
Q1: are there other ports I have to open for remote setup to access my internal server?
Q2: can I setup the server w/o the first server by only providing the system databases via filecopy? Which dbs are needed and how can I tell the remote setup tool to use them instead of trying to connect to the first server via TCPIP?

Edit:
To be clear: I can run the remote setup tool and connect to the new server but it fails when the new one wants to pull stuff from the first server.

Answer (score 0):

Remote server setup uses port 8585. Try opening that port and restart remote server setup.

Comment: You mean I have to open 8585 on the first server machine, too?

Comment: No, only on the new server that you want to set up using Remote Server Setup. The new server then connects to the existing server using port 1352

Comment: Yep, I could run remote setup and stepped though until the new server wants to connect to the first one - then BAM. I think my question was unclear.

Comment: Can the new server ping the existing server? Is port 1352 open?

Comment: Yes, ping to the host works and I tested 1352 via telnet - works

Comment: Can the new server lookup the existing server name in DNS?

Comment: Does it stop at 20%? Have you tried to connect through the ip or FQDN? I had the same issue. I tried to do the setup through the ip. When I added a host file entry with the FQDN from the server document, the setup ran through.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in the thread above works.

- Open port 8585 (Per Henrik Lausten contribution)
- Add the Fully Qualified Internet Host Name from the server document to the hosts file (Umeli contribution)
- Run server configuration with new settings